# Undefined index: password error when rename the default password field to users_password in laravel 5.5

Tags: indexing, undefined, laravel-5.5

I am new to laravel, i am using laravel 5.5 and for authentication OAuth2.0 is using. Login is working perfectly with the default email and password fields. Now i want to add two fields users_username, users_password and the authentication should be based on these fileds. When i did the same i got the below error.

> "message": "Undefined index: password", "exception": "ErrorException",
>   "file":
>   "D:\api-sample-application\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php",
>   "line": 133.

This is my code

```
 protected function login(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(['users_username' => request('username'), 'users_password' => request('password')]))
        {
            // $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            //     'email' => 'required',
            //     'password' => 'required'
            // ]);


            $request->request->add([
                                    'grant_type'    => 'password',
                                    'client_id'     => '3',
                                    'client_secret' => '6BHCRpB4tpXnQvC1DmpT7CXCSz7ukdw7IeZofiKn',
                                    'scope' => '*'
                                   ]);

            // forward the request to the oauth token request endpoint
            $tokenRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token','post');
            return Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Laravel's Eloquent/Database user providers require password to be stored in `password` column. You could build your own user provider - just follow the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers. Anyway, it seems simpler to just store password in password column.

Comment: Thank you, since i am migrating the existing software to laravel i cannot change any field in the table. However i have fixed it.

Comment: how do you fix it? Do you mind share it with the world?